# Jetty server 12 - Not able to get the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects inside handler method

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-12

we have legacy app and using the Jetty server. Now trying to upgrade our app to Java 17 with Jakarta. so we have to upgrade Jakarta 12.0.x to support java 17.
when request comes we are passing the request objects to our custom filter in our current code.

before java 17:

```
@Override
 public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest hreq, HttpServletResponse  
                    hresp)throws IOException, ServletException {
   try {
         fc.doFilter(hreq, hresp);
         
       }catch (Exception e) {
```

basically doFilter method passes HttpServletRequest hreq, HttpServletResponse hresp objects

but new Jetty server 12.0.X, we do not have HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse objects inside handle method, below is the method signature.

after Java 17 and Jetty 12.0.x

```
@Override
public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception {
```

doFilter method is from Jakarta and its signature is

```
void jakarta.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
```

Can you please guide me how to get the these object to pass to the jakarta filter

I tried using Jetty org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request object  to get HttpServletRequest/Reponse but no methods are available in it

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 12 core has no Servlet requirement.

Servlet exists only in the various environment layers.

Environments: `ee10`, `ee9`, and `ee8`.

If you want to write against the `Handler` layer in Jetty 12 Core, check the programming guide and jetty-examples projects.

- https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html
- https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples

Since you apparently want Servlet filter like mechanisms, you should look at the `Handler.Wrapper` and `Request.Wrapper` facilities.

See also

- [Missing jetty-servlet 12.0.0 dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77007560/missing-jetty-servlet-12-0-0-dependency/77010707#77010707)
- [Porting AbstractHandler implementation from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949411/porting-abstracthandler-implementation-from-jetty-11-to-jetty-12)
- [Porting to jetty 12, where's HandlerCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855590/porting-to-jetty-12-wheres-handlercollection/77861830#77861830)
- [Jetty 11 to Jetty 12 migration guide](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-migration-11-to-12)
- [New Jetty 12 Maven Coordinates](https://webtide.com/new-jetty-12-maven-coordinates/)